# Node.js binding when making socket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, bind

```
this.startServer = function(socket) {
    var client = new Client();
    client.socket = socket;
    clients.push(client);   
    // Handle incoming messages from clients.
    socket.on('data', bind(this.onSocketDataReceive, this));
}

this.onSocketDataReceive = function(data) {
    this.commandManager(client, data+"");
}
```

In this example binding solves the visibility of this, but client is not visible in onSocketDataReceive function, any ideas? if I try to pass client with bind as well, then this becomes invisible...

Comment: I can't directly awnser your question, but why not use io sockets? I believe that will be easyer. and did you check nodejs api docuentation, its pretty helpfull.

Comment: I actually didn't knew there is io sockets till now, so thanks, i'll take a look!

Comment: http://socket.io/#how-to-use This is what i use for my socket servers in nodejs, its really easy to manage your client's too. Good luck!